# move multiple csv files by column value using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have thousands of csv files under uncategorised parent folder, all the files have one date column containing same date for all the rows. I want to check the date value of each files and move/copy to month wise folder using python.

I have tried key = df.iloc[0]['Date'] but not able to use key.endswith or key.**contains**

Comment: What solutions have you tried? What is the format of these files?

Comment: pandas is a bit bloated for this task since you only need to read the header line (which based on your post it appears can be assumed to exist) and the first line of data. What is the format of the date in the 'Date' column?

Comment: @jpf Date format is YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 0):

Here I am looping through the files, reading the first row of the date column.
I have created new folders in the directory previously, with the names being each month of the year.
Once I have read the date, I convert it to words (e.g. April, May).
I then look through folders in the directory and is the date name and folder name match, I move the file to the folder.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import datetime

files = os.listdir()
for file in files:
    if ".csv" in file:
        df = pd.read_csv(file)
        dates = df['date']
        date = dates[0]
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%y")
        date = date.strftime("%B")
        for folder in files:
            if date.lower() == folder.lower():
                os.rename(file, folder+"\\"+file)
```

Comment: getting this error   date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%y")
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not numpy.int64

Comment: what format is your date in?

Comment: Date format is YYYYMMDD

Answer (score 0):

If all CSV files have the same structure, for example:

```
date, col_1, col_2, ..., col_n
20210923, 123, 456, ..., 999
```

You can try:

```
from os import mkdir
from os.path import join, exists, isdir
from glob import glob
from shutil import move
from datetime import datetime
import csv


FOLDER_CSV = 'data/csv'
FOLDER_MONTHS = 'data/csv_by_month'
DATE_FORMAT = '%Y%m%d'

if not exists(FOLDER_MONTHS):
    mkdir(FOLDER_MONTHS)
    
for file in glob(join(FOLDER_CSV, '*.csv')):
    with open(file, newline='') as ftx:
        reader = csv.reader(ftx)
        row = reader.__next__()
        row = reader.__next__()
    
    # Replaces the row[0] Index for index in the date column in the CSV
    month = datetime.strptime(row[0], DATE_FORMAT).strftime('%B').lower()
    
    if not exists(join(FOLDER_MONTHS, month)):
        mkdir(join(FOLDER_MONTHS, month))

    try:
        if isdir(join(FOLDER_MONTHS, month)):
            move(file, join(FOLDER_MONTHS, month))
    except OSError:
        print(f'{file} file is already in the {month} directory.')
```